# How long does it take for a Stack Overflow profile to propagate?

Tags: support, profile-page

When I edited my Stack Overflow profile, I clicked propagate to **all** Stack Exchange sites.

I noticed that one can not edit her/his profile at Meta.SO, so I assumed that it is interlinked with my main StackOverflow profile.

I also noticed my Meta.SO profile has not yet updated.

How long does it take for the Meta.SO profile to update?

(Actually, answer to this part: not that long, perhaps 10 to 15 minutes in my case because it's updated already).

How long does it take for updated Stack Overflow profiles to propagate throughout all Stack Exchange sites?

Comment: Many many many things are cached server side for speed, especially the profile pages.  The short answer is the profiles will update once the cache is refreshed.  I just don't know how long that typically takes, but guessing an hour, maybe more.  And it won't be the same for every site.

Comment: @psubsee2003 i've noticed that some StackExchange sites are showing my new profile already.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [because of caching](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=is%3Aa+because+of+caching)